# what is wrong with this UITableView code, where I'm using pass-by-reference to update a core data config record?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, uitextfield, pass-by-reference

I have core data configuration in my iPhone app, and how I'm currently passing the configuration to the view that allows a user to EDIT the data, is via passing the core data object by reference.  In fact I'm allocated the core data class attribute (NSString) to the "UITextField.text"  in the edit view, so that if it gets updated then it is effectively updating the core data object.  The issue is:

1. it seems to work fine when I create/update this string in the edit view
2. when I update a separate field (not the one in question) then the value seems to be null

**Question - Is there anything fundamentally wrong with this pass-by-reference approach using a core-data managed object attribute?**

Code snippets:

a) In the Edit Controller - in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        // Setup
    UITextField *titleTextField = nil;
    // Get Cell
    self.nonWorkTermCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"nonWorkTermCell"];
    if (self.nonWorkTermCell == nil) {
        self.nonWorkTermCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"nonWorkTermCell"] autorelease];
            self.nonWorkTermCell.textLabel.text = @"Non Work Term:";

            titleTextField = [[self newTextFieldForCell:self.nonWorkTermCell] autorelease];
            titleTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeURL;
            titleTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone; 
        titleTextField.delegate = self;  // TODO: Is this needed at all?
        titleTextField.tag = 1;
            [self.nonWorkTermCell addSubview:titleTextField];
    }
    // Set Value
    titleTextField.text = self.weConfig.nonWorkTerm;   // ** ASSIGNS THE CORE DATA MANAGED OBJECT CONFIG ITEM DIRECTLY TO THE TEXT FIELD

        // Return 
    return self.nonWorkTermCell;
```

b) and the helper method it uses:

```
- (UITextField *)newTextFieldForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell {
    UITextField *addTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];  //cut the code for the frame to save space
    addTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    addTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    addTextField.delegate = self;
    addTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
    addTextField.enabled = YES;
    addTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    addTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;  
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return addTextField;
}
```

c) then back in the delegate

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self saveContext];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self saveContext];
}
```

Comment: you should not set a cell's `.textLabel.text` directly, you should be setting `.text` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning a managed object's NSString property to a textField and the editing the textfield's content will **not** propagate those changes back to the managed object, for a number of reasons:

- NSString is immutable, so by definition you won't be making changes to the same object
- The object returned by an accessor on managed object could well be an autoreleased copy of the underlying value
- The textfield also probably takes a copy of whatever value is assigned to it's text property
- No changes will go back to the model unless they have passed through the managed object accessors which include the KVO notifications
- The whole idea is insane. What if I wanted to take a string that I'd got from a managed object and perform some other operation on it for presentation or analysis?

Comment: ok thanks jrturton - you've set me straight here :)   doh, even as a hobbyist I should have thought of the first bullet point...but re immutability you'd thing this would deserve an error perhaps, to highlight you're trying to set the value of an object you can't? (oh but perhaps you're point 3 explains this in the case of the textfield usage?)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like passing a dynamic core data managed property by reference may not work....?

So this answer is (for voting/confirmation) that passing a dynamic core data managed property by reference doesn't work.

[I've changed to manually setting the model via use of "textFieldDidEndEditing" which seems to fix things]

Answer (score 0):

Greg,

The line in question is:

```
titleTextField.text = self.weConfig.nonWorkTerm;
```

and `weConfig` is your managed object? and `nonWorkTerm` is an `NSString`?

If the answer to everything above is yes, then this is a supported assignment. (I'm not sure why you think this is a pass by reference. It looks like the value is being directly assigned to me. [Actually, `titleTextField` will most likely copy the string.])

What is the problem?

Andrew

Comment: yep, the answer was yes - I just kind of thought if NSString is an object then I would be able to pass-by-reference from one controller method to another - i.e. update the value in the child, then when I through back to the parent controller it should be updated there too, however this doesn't seem to work, but I note it is dynamic parameter as part of a managed core data object xcode created...